Nginx not working proxy_pass using Env Variable
I am deploying my react app using docker and nginx server.
In my nginx.conf.template, I use the following
worker_processes  1;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
 include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
 error_log  /var/log/nginx/error_log;
 access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;

server {
    listen 80;
    sendfile on;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    resolver 169.254.169.253 valid=5s;

    gzip on;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.";
    gzip_min_length   1100;
    gzip_vary         on;
    gzip_proxied      expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_types        text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
    gzip_comp_level   9;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }

    location /test {
        set $backend "${BACKEND_URL}";
        proxy_pass $backend;
    }
  }
}

When I check in my container inside nginx.conf the $backend is set to the env variable I use during build. But when I send a request to my backend with path /test I get Bad Gateway error, However if I set proxy_pass hard coded then everything works fine
Any idea what I am doing wrong?

So the solution that worked for me was the following change
location /test {
    proxy_pass https://${BACKEND_URL};
}

BACKEND_URL is set as an env variable, you don't need to specify the resolver
